# Conditionally apply QSS stylesheet to QListWidgetItem

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have QListWidgetItem and I have QSS Stylesheet that I would love to apply to QListWidgetItem conditionally, for other Widgets I would do it like this.

```
QLabel:hover
{
    font-family: Monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8pt;
}
QLabel[status=0]
{
    color: red;
}
QLabel[status=1]
{
    color: yellow;
}
```

and then in my Python code I would:

```
my_label = QLabel("Hello")
my_label.setProperty("status", 0)
# this label would end up red and it works
```

However, QListWidgetItem does not have Properties, also I cannot define my own states `QListWidget::item:my_property` or anything like that. What would be the best workaround for issue like this, I feel like such a simple thing. I really do not want to write a custom widget just for this, because QListWidget is very convenient for me, but I cannot find any solution.

Comment: If you're not using stylesheets that affect the QListWidget appearance, use `QListWidgetItem.setForeground()`, but if you need that to be dynamic and conditional, then there's no other option: either use a custom delegate, or use a custom model in QListView.

Comment: You could create a subclass of `QListWidgetItem` and reimplement its [data method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#data). This will allow you to dynamically modify any of the [properties that are accessible via item-roles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum). If you want to stick with `QListWidget`, this is probably the simplest work-around if you only need to handle basic features like icons, fonts and text/background colours.